# Is there a way to do multiple comparisons of cumulative incidence curves?

Tags: r, survival, multiple-comparisons, competing-risks

I have a plot with 5 cumulative incidence curves and I want to know which curves are different from each other. Right now I have a p-value from Gray’s test (p<0.001), which tests all the curves at once.

I considered plotting just two curves at a time and calculating a p-value, but that doesn't have corrections for multiple testing.

This question came about since I learned about the [pairwise_survdiff()](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/survminer/html/pairwise_survdiff.html) function from R’s survminer package. It doesn’t work for my data set because my status variable has 3 levels (0-censored, 1-death, 2-competing event) instead of 2 (censored and death only). I'm looking for a similar function that can be used for competing risks data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of multiple-comparison adjustment, there's nothing special about the `pairwise_survdiff()` function. It just calls the basic `p.adjust()` function in R. If you provide `p.adjust()` any numeric vector of *p*-values (e.g., for the 10 comparisons among 5 curves), it will provide corresponding *p*-values adjusted according to your choice of `method`.

The application to cumulative incidence in a competing risks situation might be a bit tricky, depending on what comparisons you are considering. I think that the above would be OK if you are just comparing cumulative incidences of a single type of outcome.

I wonder, however, whether this is the best way to evaluate your results. If this is a regression model, it's probably more informative to evaluate differences among the regression coefficients.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, I will try out p.adjust()! I am comparing cumulative incidences of the same outcome, stratified by time period. I used cuminc() (not regression), so I it sounds like that approach could work.